# How to put a Token in a path in a view Path setting?

Tags: views, tokens

I have a view page display to show some content and I added a contextual filter to filter by user id [uid]. It works fine.

I need to create the path to be shown in the **Main Menu** including the token for user id at the end of the path. Something like `/tus-lotes/[uid]`

If I try with: `/tus-lotes/%` I get this error message:

```
Views cannot create normal menu items for paths with a % in them.
```

But I see that the path doesn't accept token. How can I accomplish this?

Please look the capture: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the contextual filter settings:
**When the filter value is NOT available** -> provide default value ->User ID from url

and edit link of the view just without the argument/token

Comment: Hello, Is it working properly? Its not working for me. Am i missing something?